# How long does it take

Tags: questions, formulation-idiomatique

Google Translate gives me the following translation for **How long does it take?** translated from English:

> Combien de temps cela prend-il?

However is it correct that I might also use the phrase:

> Combien de temps faut-il?

Which one is considered the correct response when speaking to someone formally? Is there a major difference between using either phrase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a major difference between the two, both are equally formal.

However *"Combien de temps faut-il?"* does not have an object (or whatever it is called, but the "it" in "how long does it take"). The expression if *"combien de temps faut-il **pour** [...]"*.

So in you example:

> *Combien de temps faut-il pour cela?*

You *could* just say *"Combien de temps faut-il?"* if the object is really obvious, like:

> *Je veux aller à la boulangerie; combien de temps faut-il?*